# Yield statement blocks recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield

I've spent a lot of time on this issue without finding any hint... I don't understand why yield forbid my recursive function to execute, without any outputs at all.

```
def unlist(l):
    if isinstance(l, unicode) or isinstance(l, str):
        print "This should be printed at least !"
        yield l
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for elem in l:
            unlist(elem)

l = ['a', u'b', 1]

for each in unlist(l): print each
```

Any hint on where/what to look for?

Comment: Of course there is other way to iterate over a list :) this code give only an example of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'return', or in this case `yield` the results of the recursive call:

```
def unlist(l):
    if isinstance(l, unicode) or isinstance(l, str):
        print "This should be printed at least !"
        yield l
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for elem in l:
            for res in unlist(elem):
                yield res
```

The `yield` may not be strictly necessary in this case, but you need to at least *loop* over a generator to execute the contained code. You simply called `unlist(elem)` which creates the generator, but only looping over the generator causes it to execute the generator function to produce items.

Demo:

```
>>> def unlist(l):
...     if isinstance(l, unicode) or isinstance(l, str):
...         print "This should be printed at least !"
...         yield l
...     if isinstance(l, list):
...         for elem in l:
...             for res in unlist(elem):
...                 yield res
... 
>>> l = ['a', u'b', 1]
>>> for each in unlist(l): print each
... 
This should be printed at least !
a
This should be printed at least !
b
```

In Python 3.3 and newer, you can use the `yield from` syntax:

```
def unlist(l):
    if isinstance(l, unicode) or isinstance(l, str):
        print "This should be printed at least !"
        yield l
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for elem in l:
            yield from unlist(elem)
```

Last, but not least, you can use [`basestring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) to test for both `str` and `unicode`:

```
if isinstance(l, basestring):
    # either a str or a unicode value
```